# Filter a string value from a column in Python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Need to extract Diabetes value from column name chronic from a df in python.

Can anyone pls help to retrieve this in python?

```
Patients    Chronic
  1         Diabetes
  2         Diabetes
  3       Hypertension
  4       Hypertension
  5         Diabetes
```

Comment: Python doesn't have "dataframes" or "columns". I guess you are using pandas? Please always include the [tag:pandas] tag when asking such questions, as it introduces a whole new set of data types and idioms.

Comment: Assuming the above, and that your dataframe is "df", you can use `df[df["Chronic"] == "Diabetes"]` to filter for rows where the Chronic column is equal to Diabetes.

Comment: just found the values also appear as Diabetes is also Diabetes Mellitus, Diabetes type 1.

test1=df[df["Chronic"]==“Diabetes”]

 I will use the below package to retrieve visit information for patients (vector of patient ids) specific to Diabetes from test 1.

 df2=get_visit(patients, ?)

I'm unable to use the test1 to get df2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your `df` is:

```py
   Patients          Chronic
0         1         Diabetes
1         2         Diabetes
2         3     Hypertension
3         4     Hypertension
4         5  Diabetes type 1
```

Then:

```py
mask = df["Chronic"].str.contains("Diabetes")
print(df.loc[mask, "Patients"].to_list())
```

Will print list of all Patient IDs who has `"Diabetes"` in `Chronic` column:

```py
[1, 2, 5]
```